# Pandas merge dataframes with list a column and convert to json

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df1

```
id  data
1  abc     
2  def     
3  ghi     
4  jkl
```

df2

```
id    numbers
1     ['123', '456', '789']
2     ['1', '2']
3     ['3', '567']
```

When i'm trying to merge the data and convert it to json using below code:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left')
df_as_json = df1.to_json(orient='records')
```

My output comes as below:

```
[{"id" : 1, "data" : "abc", "numbers" : "['123', '456', '789']"},.....]
```

My expected output is:

```
[{"id" : 1, "data" : "abc", "numbers" : ['123', '456', '789']},.....]
```

The issue is that the **numbers** values are not converting to JSON array, they are taken as strings. Did I miss something? How can I solve this issue here?

**PS:** 
df2 is obtained by grouping by as list as below:

```
id  number
1   123
1   456
1   789
2   1
2   2

df2 = df2.groupby('id')['number'].apply(list).reset_index()
df2.columns = ['id','numbers']
```

Comment: For me it working perfectly.

Comment: What is your pandas version? Tested in pandas 0.23.4

Comment: my bad. i was converting the whole df to upper and it converted list to a string in the process